# Would you trust this starter?

Tags: starter, wort, yeast, techniques

I had one WLP001 vial of yeast that was only 14 days past its "best buy" date.  I made a starter on a stir plate 2 full days before brewing.  I got good growth as estimated by an increase in creamy opaqueness of the start wort post 2 days (looks like most starters I make, so no worries there).

Then I crash cooled it overnight, anticipating I'll pitch the slurry only the next day into a Brown Ale.

I never got to brew the brown ale sad to say.

So now I have yeast still in the fridge and settled out.  The spent starter wort still above it.

Which route is the best course of action?

1. Pitch the slurry as is after bringing it to room temp.
2. Decant spent wort and add new start wort day of brew session.
3. Ditch the whole thing and start fresh.
4. Something I didn't think of.

EDIT:
Tonight I am going to make a gallon of starter wort and awaken the yeast on the stir plate in there. Then I am going to use it for brewing tomorrow night.  I'll update on the final beer later if I remember.

Comment: How old is it?.

Comment: Tomorrow would be one week from when I first pitched into the starter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You're probably fine

Decant off most of the liquid.  Taste it.

Swirl up the slurry. Taste it.

### Be sanitary